# GDAL_GRID providing blocky raster output

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-grid

I have a shapefile containing XYZ bathymetry points.

I've been using ArcGIS Pro `Point to Raster` tool where I have specified:

```
Input: input.shp
Value Field: Z
Output: output.tiff
Cell Assignment: Minimum
Cellsize: 2
```

I am now trying to find the equivalent tool in GDAL, which I think is `gdal_grid`.

I have altered the radius as 2 which I assumed was the same as ArcGIS cellsize, but I am getting very block results. See code below that I am trying:

```
gdal_grid -zfield Z[m] -a minimum:radius1=2.0:radius2=2.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff input.shp output.tiff
```

See raster differences below:

GDAL
[image: GDAL Minimum output]

ArcGIS
[image: ArcGIS Pro Minimum output]

How can I achieve better results in GDAL so that comparison between the two is more accurate?

**edit - gdalinfo of shapefile**

```
Layer name: input
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2022-03-30
Geometry: 3D Point
Feature Count: 510518
Extent: (626066.430000, 231758.200000) - (628085.430000, 234095.200000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB36",
        DATUM["Ordnance Survey of Great Britain 1936",
            ELLIPSOID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4277]],
    CONVERSION["British National Grid",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",49,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-2,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996012717,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",400000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",-100000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49┬░45'N to 61┬░N and 9┬░W to 2┬░E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore."],
        BBOX[49.75,-9,61.01,2.01]],
    ID["EPSG",27700]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
X[m]: Real (24.15)
Y[m]: Real (24.15)
Z[m]: Real (24.15)
```

Comment: So you managed to see the shades in your output. Now you should create smaller pixels by adding `-tr` with reasonable values. What is the pixel of your ArcGIS image?

Comment: @user30184 how do I find that?

Comment: With gdalinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

Comment: @user30184 according to gdal info it says ```Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)```

Comment: Then `gdal_grid -zfield Z[m] -a minimum:radius1=2.0:radius2=2.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -tr 2 2 input.shp output.tiff` should yield the same. Check also what is the pixel size of your current gdal_grid output.

Comment: @user30184  I've tried ```tr 2 2``` but I get the error ```ERROR 5: Invalid txe or tye parameters detected```

Comment: Sorry, my advice was incomplete. Please add into your question the extent of your data. You can get it with `ogrinfo -al -so input.shp` or from the corner coordinates of the gdalinfo report of your ArcGIS output tiff.

Comment: @user30184 I've included the info obtained using gdalinfo above. The extent returned ```(626066.430000, 231758.200000) - (628085.430000, 234095.200000)```

Comment: There you get the values for the missing x and y extents https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html. `-txe 626066 628085 -tye 231758 234095 -tr 2 2`